# How to redirect user after submitting form with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm learning React. I have a login page with a form ("/login") which after submitting successfully I wanna redirect the user to the root path ("/") of the domain. I'm using Redux that seems to work fine. My code is:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()

        setSubmitBtn(true)

        setTimeout(async (e) => {

            const { data } = await axios.post( axiosURL + '/login', inputs)

            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN' })

            history.push("/")

            setReturnMessage(data.message)

            setSubmitBtn(false)

        }, 1000)
    }
```

The problem is the `history.push("/")` that's not working and it gives the following error message:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Login (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at routes.js:36)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you are doing this after `history.push("/")`:

```
setReturnMessage(data.message) 
setSubmitBtn(false)
```

Comment those lines and the error should disappear.

You can also do this:

```
setReturnMessage(data.message)
setSubmitBtn(false)
history.push("/")  <--- as the last line of code
```